# how to use domains properly in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-domains

I try to use `domains` core module instead of `process.on('uncaughtException')`, to catch error

```
function setupDomains(req, res, next) {
    var reqd = domain.create();

    reqd.add(req);
    reqd.add(res);
    reqd.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      req.next(err);
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log('disposing domain for url ' + req.url);
      reqd.dispose();
    });
    reqd.run(next);
}
```

and use as middleware in express
but it seems that

```
 res.on('end', function() {
      console.log('disposing domain for url ' + req.url);
      reqd.dispose();
    });
```

is not called

I want to dispose the domains when the respond end

how to do that properly, or maybe I don't have to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best example I have found of how to do this comes from the node.js documentation.

http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors

As Identified near the beginning of this page, it's a bad idea to catch the exception, log and move on. Instead you should log it and restart the process.

The example contained in the documentation will shut down the node process where the exception occurred and restart a new one. This is the preferred option to calling `dispose` and moving on to the next request.

If you are certain that you want to `dispose` of the members of the domain, you would just place the call to dispose at the beginning of the `domain.on('error')` handler as detailed in this [post](http://www.lighthouselogic.com/use-domain-dispose/).

Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if indeed it is.